# Merging data from dimensions of different grains

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensions, dimensional-modeling

I am using an RDBMS and writing an equivalent of an ETL program, though without tools like Informatica etc.

The source data comes from three different tables, each with a different level of data storage, its all per account, but the SCD-type-2 behavior makes number of rows variable.  Also, one of the sources has data on a "per day" basis, i.e. one row per day.

The need is to merge this data (finally 5 attributes) into a single table, to facilitate lookup on account number and date. Effectively providing a lookup service to the extent of "whats the value of this attribute on this day" for a given account.

The challenge primarily is on leveling the "grain" of the records. Couple of brute force ideas are there. One is to explode the variable grain rows, and generate additional rows to level with the lowest grain attribute. Effectively having one row per day for each attribute.  This doesn't look clean to me and will consume much more storage too. Here's an example -

**Source** -

```
table 1 (Customer Details)
Address - dt1 - dt2 - val1
Address - dt2+1 - dt3 - val2
Address - dt3+1 - infinity - val3

table 2 (Loan Details)
Maturity Date - dt4 - dt5 - val8
Maturity Date - dt5+1 - dt6 - val-x
Maturity Date - dt6+1 - dt7 - val-xx
Maturity Date - dt7+1 - infinity - val-y

table 3 (Account Balance) (one record per day)
Daily Interest Accrued - dt1 - val1
Daily Interest Accrued - dt2 - val2
Daily Interest Accrued - dt3 - val3
```

**Target**

```
dt1 - Address-val - Maturity Date-val - Daily Interest Accrued-val
dt2 - Address-val - Maturity Date-val - Daily Interest Accrued-val
dt3 - Address-val - Maturity Date-val - Daily Interest Accrued-val
```

These three attributes need to be stored in a single table... ideas please..

Comment: Tell us what the tables are, such as ACCOUNT and ACCOUNT-BALANCE, rather than making up names. It will help us to understand the problem better, and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: @RonDunn - Added real table name/references. Hope it makes things a bit clearer.. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's deal with the modelling, first.

In the absence of any more details, I think you've got a periodic snapshot for ACCOUNT-BALANCE, a DATE dimension, a Type-2 slowly changing dimension for CUSTOMER, and a Type-1 dimension for LOAN.

The attributes of FACT_ACCOUNT look like DIM_DATE_ID, DIM_CUSTOMER_ID, DIM_LOAN_ID, ACCRUED_INTEREST, ACCOUNT_BALANCE.

The reason I don't think you've got a Type-2 dimension for LOAN is because I don't see its values - such as account number, maturity date and original balance - changing over time.

By moving the ACCOUNT_BALANCE from the dimension to the fact table you've got a better representation of the process.

One question which will probably arise is the storage of an interest rate. A fixed rate would be an attribute of an SCD1 dimension. A periodically changing rate could be an SCD2 value. If it changed at the same grain as the fact table (ie, daily) I'd make it a non-additive measure.

I did see your point about storing three attributes in one table, but I don't see its purpose. If the attributes that are needed to satisfy a query are in different tables, that is the role of a JOIN. Any competent visualisation or analytics tool is going to support simple joins like this.